# moment js calculates months differently in different instances

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am using Moment JS to add dates. I want to add 2 months from today. I find these two lines of code to add two months give different results

```
// Today 29 03 2021
 moment().add(2, 'M').format('DD MM YYYY') // prints 29 03 2021
 moment().add(1, 'M').add(1, 'M').format('DD MM YYYY') //prints 28 03 2021
```

Can somebody explain why do we get different results and what is the right way to use moment js add function.

Thanks

Comment: If you're just starting with momentjs... -> _"Considering using Moment in your project? There may be better modern alternatives. For more details and recommendations, please see [Project Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) in the docs."_ ([Source](https://momentjs.com/))

Comment: Your case is explicitly mentioned in the docs for [`.add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/): _"Special considerations for months and years: If the day of the month on the original date is greater than the number of days in the final month, the day of the month will change to the last day in the final month."_; `.add(1, 'M')` would be `2021-02-29` which does not exist hence it is "truncated" to `2021-02-28`. In the `.add(2, 'M')` case you skip that case.

Comment: I think you mean "*Today is 29 01 2021*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the way how [`.add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) works:

> Special considerations for months and years
>
> If the day of the month on the original date is greater than the number of days in the final month, the day of the month will change to the last day in the final month.
>
> ```
> moment([2010, 0, 31]);                  // January 31
> moment([2010, 0, 31]).add(1, 'months'); // February 28
> ```